# Как добавить кнопку слева в actionbar

Tags: java, android

Как добавить кнопку слева в actionbar?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая вам кнопка нужна. Если просто родная кнопка назад, то [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150205/android-action-bar-home-button) в вопросе есть код для ее активации, а в ответе - для обработки нажатия

Еще если добавить шаблонную активити с Navigation Drawer, то добавится объект класса Toggle, который анимирует эту кнопочку из трех полосок в стрелку и обратно

Если нужна своя кнопка, то нужно писать [кастомную разметку](https://www.journaldev.com/9952/android-custom-action-bar-example-tutorial) для ActionBar